# Cannot find type System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase in module System.dll

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I've been away from C# Forms programming for 7+ years and boy, have things changed!

None of my old projects work, and when I can seem to get one slightly working my breakpoints do not want to work! Wow Microsoft, I love the hoops you want people to jump through.

Anyways, I started fresh making a C# UWP Form project from scratch and got stuck with a weird error I can not seem to find the answer to.

My project does not complain about anything until I press 'F5' to start debugging, then the error in Title pops up. No line number, just the error.[image]

What the hell does Microsoft expect me to do?

The only thing I did was add 'System.Web' as a reference, which I could not locate in the 'Add Reference' section, so I manually navigated to it.

What I thought would be a few hours to get acclimated back to C# programming(Javasript/PHP for last 7 years) has now turned into days.

PLEASE HELP ME BEFORE I LOSE MY MIND.

Comment: add reference to "System.Collections.Specialized"

Comment: UWP is a mess, I agree. If @AnirudhaGupta's suggestion does not work, I suggest you clear the Nuget cache and perform a Nuget restore.

Comment: Didn't help. Will try the Nuget restore.

Comment: Why did you want to use 'System.Web'?

Comment: So I could make HttpWebRequest

Comment: @Illuminati In general, we use [Windows.Web.Http Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Web.Http) APIs to make http request in UWP. But, anyway, could you please provide a [mcve] to show me what you have done?

Answer (score 2):

Go through these steps:

1. Right-click on your Project
2. Click on Manage NuGet packages
3. Type "`System.Collections.Specialized`" into the search box
4. Download the package and install

Comment: This would be .Net framework assembly not Nuget Package